# Add a button in Header File in Odoo (POS)

Tags: odoo-10, point-of-sale

I'm facing problem in creating a new image button in Header line in POS (Odoo). I'm attaching an image to show you where I want this lock-image.(Somewhere between odoo symbol and Administrator)[image]
Here's what I've done in my xml file. (All files are perfectly included in **manifest**.py).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="Chrome">
        <t t-jquery="div.pos-branding img.pos-logo" t-operation="after">
            <span class="order-button lock_button">
                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: Please, answer! I need this asap.

Answer (score 2):

**(Sloved) Add a button icon in Header File in Odoo @v10 (POS)**

**`Code` :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-extend="Chrome">
           <t t-jquery="div.pos-branding img.pos-logo" t-operation="after">
             <span>
                 <i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </span>
           </t>
        </t>  
   </templates>
```

Also attach Image : [image]

Comment: great! can we send pos receipt to partner or save it in odoo.?